# Inserting a URL in QTextDocument

Tags: qt

I'm using the QTextDocument for generation of PDF reports. I just can't figure out how to insert URLs in QTextDocument. I even don't know if it is supported or not. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with HTML :

```
// Your HTML code
QString html;
html = "<html><head>"
       "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='format.css'>"
       "</head><body>"
       "Your HTML code with tags, which have classes or ids. For example "
       "<span class='red'>this text is colored red</span>.<br/>"
       "And you can also display images: <img src='myImage.png'><br/>"
       "Combine css and images: <span id='bgimage'>foo bar</span>"
       "</body></html>";

// Your CSS code
QString css;
css  = "span.red { color:#DE0000; } "
       "span#bgimage { background-image: url('bg.png'); } ";

// Crate a QTextDocument with the defined HTML, CSS and the images
QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument;

/*
 * And now bind the css, which you have defined in the QString css.
 */
doc->addResource( QTextDocument::StyleSheetResource, QUrl( "format.css" ), css );
doc->setHtml( html ); // binds the HTML to the QTextDocument
```